# Compute (and print) the following sums using vector arithmetic and sum function

Tags: r

I'm trying to write 1/2−2/3+3/4−4/5+ ⋯ +999/1000 with R.
I find out that the seq is the top of first fractions is from 1,to=? by 2,
and the bottom is from 2 to ? by 2
the questions is to what value ?

```r
b1 <- seq(1,1000,2)
b2 <- seq(2,1000,2)
b12 <- b1/b2
b3 <- seq(2,?,2)
b4 <- seq(3,?,2)
```

Comment: `?=999` and `sum(b1/b2) - sum(b3/b4)`

Comment: thank you, even the bottom of the last value is 1000, I want to know also 999/1000 from what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an alternating series like this, it's probably easier to have a separate term to give the `sign` of each term. For example, you are adding `1/2`, then subtracting `2/3`, then adding `3/4` then subtracting `4/5` etc. One way to think of this is a series of `1/2, -2/3, 3/4, -4/5`. Then you just take the sum of those terms.

To construct such a series I first determine the top of each fraction as a vector (`1, 2, 3, 4`), then the bottom (`2, 3, 4, 5`) and the sign (`+` or `-`). To get an alternating sign you can raise `-1` to integer powers. E.g. `-1^1 = -1`, `-1^2 = 1`, `-1^3 = -1`...

Finally, to get the actual series you divide the `top` by the `bottom` and then multiply by the `sign`.

```r
# length of series
n <- 999

# generate parts of fraction
top <- 1:n 
bottom <- top + 1
sign <- (-1)^top

# calculate actual fractions in series
fract <- top * sign / bottom

# report sum of first n terms
sum(fract)
#> [1] -0.6926474
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Dan could tell me why we multiply by : sign <- (-1)^top. more detail please. thanks you

Comment: See updated answer with more explaination